# Different date in a query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a trouble in my lumen/laravel rest api

When I do a query on the database, the fields that contains a date, ex. `(16/09/2015 14:18:25)`, in the view on my app, the dates appear with a different hour, ex `(16/09/2015 20:42:40)`

Any have a idea what happen?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you live in central Europe and the server has a different timezone because it is in the USA, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel defines the default timezone of the app in `config/app.php`:

```
 'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

By default this is UTC, but you can change it to your timezone to save values as local time. For me, this is:

```
'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Here is a list of timezones supported by PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I tried your suggest this but not work for me. I Solved the problem put this line in .env file "DB TIMEZONE=-01:00"